# Google places details opening_hours

Tags: javascript, google-places

I am trying to use hours of operation for each business that is found in Google Places. This example searches for hotels nearby. In the try/catch statement near the bottom of this code is my attempt at retrieving the hours of each business. If I use this code to iterate through the names of each business with place.name in an alert, it works fine. I am using an alert on variable 'open' to test. I will be sending the hours to a list in the DOM later. Right now, the try/catch statement is catching every time. These business in my area do have hours posted so I am expecting data back from places details and an alert showing me that I have gotten that data.

```
var map, infoWindow, bizInfoWindow;
var options = {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 14
    }
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('recMap'), options);

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
bizInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        }; 

        var windowContent = 
        '<p>My Location</p>';
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(windowContent);
        //infoWindow.open(map);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position:pos,
              map:map,
              icon:'LYNQImages/rainbowFlagIcon.png'
          });
        map.setCenter(pos);
          marker.addListener('click', function(){
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });

          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: pos,
          radius: 3000,
          type: ['hotel']
        }, callback);

      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });


    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    } 

}
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
        createList(results[i]);
      }
    }
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      bizInfoWindow.setContent(place.name);
      bizInfoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
}

var i = 0;
function createList(place) {
    try {
        var open = place.opening_hours.periods[i].open.time;
        alert(open);
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert("No hours.");
    }
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nearby places api returns a list of places and the opening hours object looks like this:

```
"opening_hours" : {
   "open_now" : true (boolean value indicating if the place is open at the current time)      
}
```

But to get the opening hours, you need to make another call to [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests) API with Place Id. Here you will get a response like this:

> **opening_hours** contains the following information:
>
> **open_now** is a boolean value indicating if the place is open at the current time.
>   **periods[]** is an array of opening periods covering seven days
>
> **open** contains a pair of day and time objects describing when the place opens: day a number from 0–6, corresponding to the days of the
>   week. Along with 
>   **time** may contain a time of day in 24-hour hhmm format (values are in the range 0000–2359). The time will be reported in the place’s
>   timezone.
>
> **close** may contain a pair of day and time objects describing when the place closes.

To be sure, check the json response you get.

Try var open = place.opening_hours.toString();
This will give *true* if it is open at the time of request, otherwise *false*. To get the opening time, make call to *place details*.

Comment: Thank you for the response Aarushi. Are you able to provide an example for getting the opening times? I feel like I should be using the business ID in order to get them. As many times as I have been over the documentation, I can't seem to get it working. Thanks!