# Grabbing opening hours from google places API

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am using [this python library](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html) to grab a response from the google places API.

Using the places function from the above library returns the object you see below. You can see that is just gives me a boolean on whether the restaurant is open or closed. **How can I see the hours it is open for each day of the week?** If this library isnt capable of it, can anyone show me an example that is?

Here is the line of code making the request for full context.

```
import googlemaps # https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='apiKey')
response = gmaps.places(query=charlestonBars[idx], location=charleston)
```

```
[   {   'business_status': 'OPERATIONAL',
        'formatted_address': '467 King St, Charleston, SC 29403, United States',
        'geometry': {   'location': {'lat': 32.7890988, 'lng': -79.9386229},
                        'viewport': {   'northeast': {   'lat': 32.79045632989271,
                                                         'lng': -79.93725907010727},
                                        'southwest': {   'lat': 32.78775667010727,
                                                         'lng': -79.93995872989272}}},
        'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/bar-71.png',
        'icon_background_color': '#FF9E67',
        'icon_mask_base_uri': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/bar_pinlet',
        'name': "A.C.'s Bar & Grill",
------->'opening_hours': {'open_now': True},
        'photos': [   {   'height': 1816,
                          'html_attributions': [   '<a '
                                                   'href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106222166168758671498">Lisa '
                                                   'Royce</a>'],
                          'photo_reference': 'ARywPAKpP_eyNL_y625xWYrQvSjAI91TzEx4XgT1rwCxjFyQjEAwZb2ha9EgE2RcKJalrZhjp0yTWa6QqvPNU9c7GeNBTDtzXVI0rHq2RXtTySGu8sjcB76keFugOmsl1ix4NnDVh0NO0vt_PO3nIZ-R-ytOzzIRhJgPAJd3SxKNQNfEyVp5',
                          'width': 4032}],
        'place_id': 'ChIJk6nSrWt6_ogRE9KiNXVG5KA',
        'plus_code': {   'compound_code': 'Q3Q6+JG Charleston, South Carolina',
                         'global_code': '8742Q3Q6+JG'},
        'price_level': 1,
        'rating': 4.3,
        'reference': 'ChIJk6nSrWt6_ogRE9KiNXVG5KA',
        'types': [   'bar',
                     'restaurant',
                     'point_of_interest',
                     'food',
                     'establishment'
```

Comment: I would like to use the google places API if possible. Google has documentation that shows an object being returned with the hours of each day, but it is in javascript.

Comment: Here is the documentation I am referring to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50747378/19813684

Comment: @elebur that's not what OP wants. they want to fetch the weekly schedule of a business which is actually a result of the web service as per the link to the documentation OP provided on their comment above.

Comment: And to be clear, I am completely okay with using a different library/method. I would like to stay within Python but I am not limited to this library.

Comment: The library you used is fine. I was able to provide a solution using it. You should check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you need to use is the `Place Details` of Places API

Before we proceed with the solution, we must understand that there's a difference in the result of a **[Place Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search)** and a **[Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details)** request.

According to the documentation:

> *"**Place Search** requests and **Place Details** requests do not return the same fields. Place Search requests return a subset of the fields that are returned by Place Details requests. If the field you want is not returned by Place Search, you can use Place Search to get a **place_id**, then use that Place ID to make a Place Details request."*

Now what you used on your code according to the [python library documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html#googlemaps.Client.places:%7E:text=places(*args%2C%20**kwargs)) is the `places(*args, **kwargs)` which is the **Place Search**.

The Google Maps API documentation you provided on your comment above where you can get the expected result of **hours each day** is from **Place Details** which is the `place(*args, **kwargs)` from the [python library documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html#googlemaps.Client.places:%7E:text=place(*args%2C%20**kwargs)).

As quoted above, to request the detail of a place, you need the `place_id` which you can get by doing a **Places Search** request like you did on your question. So what you only need to do is get the `place_id` of the location you want through **Place Search**, then use that `place_id` to get the **Place Details** result that includes the `opening_hours` field result.

Here's what it looks like on a python code:

```
# I used pprint to print the result on the console

from pprint import pprint
import googlemaps #import googlemaps python library

# Instantiate the client using your own API key

API_KEY = 'API_KEY'
map_client = googlemaps.Client(API_KEY)

# Store the location you want, in my case, I tried using 'Mall of Asia'

location_name = 'Mall of Asia'

# Instantiate Place Search request using `places(*args, **kwargs)` from the library
# Use the `stored location` as an argument for query

place_search = map_client.places(location_name)

# Get the search results

search_results = place_search.get('results')

# Store the place_id from the result to be used

place_id = (search_results[0]['place_id'])

# Instantiate Place Details request using the `place(*args, **kwargs)` from the library
# Use the stored place_id as an argument for the request

place_details = map_client.place(place_id)

# Get the Place Details result

details_results = place_details.get('result')

# Print the result specifying what you only need which is the `opening_hours` field

pprint(details_results['opening_hours'])
```

The result of this sample request would be this:

```
{'open_now': False,
 'periods': [{'close': {'day': 0, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 0, 'time': '1000'}},
             {'close': {'day': 1, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 1, 'time': '1000'}},
             {'close': {'day': 2, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 2, 'time': '1000'}},
             {'close': {'day': 3, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 3, 'time': '1000'}},
             {'close': {'day': 4, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 4, 'time': '1000'}},
             {'close': {'day': 5, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 5, 'time': '1000'}},
             {'close': {'day': 6, 'time': '2200'},
              'open': {'day': 6, 'time': '1000'}}],
 'weekday_text': ['Monday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM',
                  'Tuesday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM',
                  'Wednesday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM',
                  'Thursday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM',
                  'Friday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM',
                  'Saturday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM',
                  'Sunday: 10:00\u202fAM\u2009–\u200910:00\u202fPM']}
```

That would be all and I hope this helps! Feel free to comment below if this does not meet your expected results.